# spring boot does not support dynamic key in application yaml for map

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

In my spring boot application, I am mapping my yaml properties to java map

Please find the code

```
url-mapping:
  authmap:
    ${id:EMP01} : ${name:selva}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "url-mapping")
public class UrlMappingProperties {

    private Map<String, String> authmap;

    public Map<String, String> getAuthmap() {
        return authmap;
    }

    public void setAuthmap(Map<String, String> authmap) {
        this.authmap = authmap;
    }
}
```

When I am printing the map my output is

```
Expected:
{EMP01=selva}

Actual
{IDEMP01=selva}
```

Unable to use dynamic key in spring boot.

Tried below approach

```
 id : &reference ${id:EMP01} 
 url-mapping:
      authmap:
        *reference : ${name:selva}
```

Still its printing IDEMP01

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

My dude;

I hope this link ( https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml ) is helpful for you. It is the tutorial for using your code's **yaml** file.

If it wasn't helpful, try this one ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html ). This is the full document of Spring Boot.